# Angular - sum up number values inside nested *ngFor directive

Tags: angular, ngfor

I want to display some number values from an array of objects, the object itself is containing an array containing some specific data.

i tried going through the values with an *ngFor but the numbers that i am getting are displayed as a concatenation between the different values while i want  to sum them up, here's a brief explanation of what i am facing :

the class "Order" :

```
export class OrdreMission{
    public idOrder:number;    
    // other attributes here
    public concern:Concern [];
    public costs:costs[];
    constructor(){
        this.mission = new Mission();    
        this.costs= [];
        this.concern = [];
    }
}
```

**how i am looping through my array (ofc after getting the appropriate data from my backend provider)**

```
     <table>
            <thead> <!-- my headers --> </thead>
            <tbody> 
                <tr *ngFor="let x of listOrders">
                            <!-- other data displayed here -->
                            <td>
                                <span *ngFor="let k of l.costs">
                                    {{k.typeCost.code=="0808" && k!=undefined && k.idOrder==l.costs.idOrder?k.value:return}}
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span #old value="0" *ngFor="let x of l.costs">{{x.typeCost.code!="0808" && x.typeCost.code!="0606"  && x!=undefined && x.idOrder==l.costs.idOrder? sum(old.value,x.value):return}}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span #old2 value="0" *ngFor="let o of l.costs">{{o.typeCost.code!="0606"  && o!=undefined && o.idOrder==l.costs.idOrder?sum(old2.value,o.value):return}}</span>
                            </td>
                          <td>
                               <span #old3 value="0" *ngFor="let m of l.costs">{{m.typeCost.code=="0606"  && m!=undefined && m.idOrder==l.costs.idOrder?sum(old3.value,m.value):return}}
                              </span>
                          </td>
                            <!-- other unrelated data here-->
                </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

sum() method in my component :

```
 sum(old:any,a:any):number{
    if(!Number(old)){
      return Number(a+0);
    }
    else if (!Number(old) && !Number(a)){
      return 0;
    }
    return  Number(a)+Number(old);
  }
```

the results that i am getting are concatenated  such as this :

[image]

As you can see the result displayed in last column is a concatenation between the first and second columns values,

that same column should be  including the sum of the two previous columns and other values, but it's just making a concatenation.

Comment: use `+a+old` or `Number(a)+parseInt(old)` similarly for other `return Number(a)+0;`

Comment: tried it but still the same result

Comment: Why you want to display one value with `*ngFor`? Use some method in component - pass parameter to it from template if thats necessary

Comment: which result you added in image, unable to undertand the code, why did you used `ngFor` multiple times, you can use that single time and write a condition

Comment: i used ngfor because i have a nested array inside each object of that "listOrders" array, and i want to loop through it so i can get my data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by using dedicated methods in my component,

seems like my approach of extracting the numbers in my template was wrong, the template could'nt differenciate between Numbers and strings in my case, so it just considerates it a string value no matter what the provided type is.

below is my new approach :

```
getTotal(val:Costs[]):number{
    let sum = 0;
    if(val!=undefined){
      val.forEach(element => {
        if(element.typeCost.code!="0606") sum+=element.value; 
      });   
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

and in HTML i used :

```
<td>{{getTotal(l.costs)}}</td>
```